# finding a linear map over natural numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Consider a map $f$ from $\mathbb{N}^N$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ as follows:

$$
f(n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_N) = n_1 m_1 + n_2 m_2 + \cdots + n_N m_N.
$$

Where $n_i$'s are natural numbers with $0\leq n_i \leq M$. The question is to determine the integer numbers $m_i$ such that:

1. The map needs **not** to be one to one, but given a $k \leq M$, the value of function at $p = (k, k, \cdots, k)$ should be unique. In other words, if $q=f(p)$ then
   $$y=f^{-1}(q) \implies y = p $$
2. The value of $|f(p)|$ should be as small as possible.

My try:

I used a map similar to binary representation ($M'=M+1$):
$$
f(n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_N) = n_1  + n_2 M' + n_3 M'^2 + \cdots + n_N M'^{N-1}
$$
it satisfies first condition but the value of $q$ can be large of order $M^N$. Can we do better?